# Отправка в MySQL значений

Tags: xhtml, html, html5, php

Есть форма добавления оборудования, в ней есть текстовое поле, куда можно ввести текст, и он передастся в БД, и рядом надо поставить checkbox, что бы можно было или ввести значение в поле или передавать "зафиксированное" значение, нажимая на checkbox.

***Пример** (рассмотрим ввод IP адреса устройства):*

1. В поле можно ввести IP адрес (если он есть)
2. или же нажать на checkbox(если устройство не имеет IP), при нажатии на ЧекПоинт, передаётся в БД фраза - "Не имеет"

И главное, если мы вписываем текст в поле, то передаётся одно значение, а если ставим checkbox, то передаётся другое значение, но в ОДНУ графу

Вопрос: как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript вам в руки. По нажатию на checkbox записываем в текстовое поле "Не имеет" и дизэйблим поле. Можно запоминать значение, которое было в текстовом поле до нажатия, и по второму нажатию на checkbox писать в поле старое значение. Ещё вариант - на submit формы вешаем обработчик, который проверяет, был ли нажат checkbox, и если был, то вместо введённого в текстовое поле значения подставляет "Не имеет".

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip">
<input type="checkbox" name="ip_check">Нет IP
<br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
isset($_POST['ip_check'])?$ip="Не имеет":$ip=$_POST['ip'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

наглядно покажет.

для того, чтобы форма ввода переходила в статус disable, нужно добавить еще javascript код.